# How to write this in comprehension list Python

Tags: python, list

I got a list of list and retrieving the first sublist (element to element) to the others sublist.

```
ListA=[[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

would give `ListB=[[0,0,0],[2,2,2],[5,5,5]]`

How code this in a comprehension list?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show you're current code ?

Comment: What exactly is the logic behind getting from `ListA` to `ListB`? It is not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Looks like `ListB = [[0 for _ in ListA[0]], [ListA[0] for _ in ListA[1]], [ListA[1] for _ in ListA[2], ...]`.

Comment: I also don't follow what's the logic to get ListB from ListA, could you please add an explanation about that?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListA=[[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

ListB = [[sublist[i] - ListA[0][i] for i in range(len(sublist))] for sublist in ListA]

print (ListB)
```

This prints:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5]]
```

Also, make sure that all sub-lists in `ListA` are of the same length.

Comment: If it is an empty list, "difference between two sublists" doesn't make sense. For a single element, the difference is between the same (sole) sublist, which is not an issue here.

Comment: @superbrain Note that he mentions "first sublist" in his question. An empty list cannot have a 'first' sublist if there are no elements in the lists to even begin with. For an empty list, this raises an ambiguity, atleast for the sake of formality of the problem statement. What do you say?

Comment: Meh, the question is so horribly written that I wouldn't put much weight on any of it. In any case, if that were a problem somehow, it would be their problem. I was just surprised *you* talked about it. It's not like your solution would fail if ListA were empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this

```
>>> ListA=[[2,3,4],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [[j-i for i,j in zip(ListA[0], l)] for l in ListA]
[[0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 2], [5, 5, 5]]
```